# Not able to get a subquery working

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a problem. The problem is that I am not able to get a simple Query working. I am using MS-Access.
Basically I have to make a invoice (Factuur) that gets the Premises (Borg). I am using this Query

```
SELECT  Factuur.FactuurNR,Prijzen.Borg
FROM Prijzen, Factuur
WHERE Klasse IN
(SELECT Autos.Klasse
FROM Autos, Factuur
WHERE Autos.AutoNR = Factuur.AutoNR);
```

But with that Query I am getting all the InvoiceNR's with all the Premises possible behind it.
Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

But when I try and execute the subquery only it

```
SELECT Autos.Klasse
FROM Autos, Factuur
WHERE Autos.AutoNR = Factuur.AutoNR
```

It gives me the correct Car Class.

[image]

The only thing I need is that the Premises that matches with the correct Invoice.
The premises is based on car class. The premises are located in the Prijzen table.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JOIN`. Try this way:

```
SELECT  Factuur.FactuurNR,Prijzen.Borg
FROM ((Prijzen 
     INNER JOIN Autos ON Autos.Klasse = Prijzen.Klasse)
     INNER JOIN Factuur ON Factuur.AutoNR = Autos.AutoNR)
GROUP BY Factuur.FactuurNR,Prijzen.Borg;
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, the problem was with in the subquery when you try to execute it separately it gives you the result. But when you combine it with main query it wont work so add a group by in the sub query and gives the answer.
Ex: "SELECT Autos.Klasse
FROM Autos, Factuur
WHERE Autos.AutoNR = Factuur.AutoNR group by Prijzen.Borg";

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT Autos.Klasse
FROM Autos, Factuur
WHERE Autos.AutoNR = Factuur.AutoNR);
```

Returns a scalar (singular) value.

So when you do  Klasse = (SELECT ...).  It is equivalent to writing Klasse = true, or Klasse = 3, or Klasse = null.